# How to load dynamic record from database mysql in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

Here I want to load database user in select box using angular.

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl" class="centered">
  <label>Select User</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in list">
        <option value="">-- choose --</option>
    </select>
     <h2>Selected:</h2>
        {{selectedItem.name}}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "http://localhost/demo/angular/getdata.php"
}).then(
function (response) {
   $scope.list = response.data.records;
});
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: i used angular version 2

Comment: Output : {"records":[{Name : "Reena"},{Name : "Diya"},{Name : "New"},{Name : "New1"},{Name : "Diya"},{Name : "Sonali"
},{Name : "Sonali"},{Name : "Sonali"},]}

Comment: There is no return param in PHP, Use "return $outp" then try again, and its angular 1 you are using  not angular 2.

Comment: your command seems you are using angular 1.x its not 2.x

Comment: yes angular 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynemic Select box</title>   
<!---load css-->
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!---load js-->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/Javascript" ></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/Javascript" ></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/Javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body 
<?php 
     echo $header;
     $userdata=$this->model_user->getuser();
     $userdata =json_encode($userdata);
   ?>
 <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl" class="centered">
 <label>Select User</label>
 <select ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in sample" ng-model="x.id" name="selectedItem" id="selectedItem">

    <h2>Selected:</h2>
    {{selectedItem.name}}
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.sample=<?php echo $userdata;?>;
});
</script>
</body>
</htnl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fully depend on the back-end. If the back-end is a RESTFull service then it is much easy to get data from the server and fill a form.

By the way, getting data from a back-end is independent of Programming languages. Here is an example in Java+Angularjs

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/

And this is an example that show how to implement a RESTFull API in PHP:

https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

Error in json if you see extra , after last object. Marked as bold below also Name should be like "Name".

Output : {"records":[{Name : "Reena"},{Name : "Diya"},{Name : "New"},{Name : "New1"},{Name : "Diya"},{Name : "Sonali" },{Name : "Sonali"},{Name : "Sonali"}**,**]}

Suggestion:

Why you use cocatenate string to form json. You can use json_encode the array.

Comment: <select class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in list | filter: string">
<option class="" value="" selected="selected">-- choose --</option>
<option label="undefined" value="string:Reena"></option>
<option label="undefined" value="string:Diya"></option>
<option label="undefined" value="string:New"></option>
<option label="undefined" value="string:New1"></option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

Mistake you done was, `item.name` in your `JSON` you have `item.Name` rename it . it will work

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl" class="centered">
  <label>Select User</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.Name for item in list">
        <option value="">-- choose --</option>
    </select>
     <h2>Selected:</h2>
        {{selectedItem.Name}}
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
        app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.list = {"records":[{Name : "Reena"},{Name : "Diya"},{Name : "New"},{Name : "New1"},{Name : "Diya"},{Name : "Sonali" },{Name : "Sonali"},{Name : "Sonali"},]};
            $scope.list = $scope.list.records;
            /* replace it with your request data
            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : "http://localhost/demo/angular/getdata.php"
            }).then(
            function (response) {
               $scope.list = response.data.records;
            });
            */
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i used ng-option instead of ng-repeat  Because the ng-repeat directive repeats a block of HTML code for each item in an array, it can be used to create options in a dropdown list, but the ng-options directive was made especially for filling a dropdown list with options.

Comment: didnt get exactly what you need . do you want to load options or block? your code have options . so you want to load data based on drop down select choice ?

Comment: i want load option

Comment: in your JSON you have 'Name' is capital but you using 'name'. rename it it will work

Comment: output array : ["Reena","Diya","New","New1","Diya","Sonali","Sonali","Sonal‌​i"]

Comment: so you want to get above array right ? then use this code to get, new_list = [] ; for(i in $scope.list) { new_list.push(a['records'][i]['Name'])}

Answer (score 0):

It's because your JSON array uses `Name` and your ng-options uses `name`.

Change your PHP so it uses `name` instead of `Name`.

---

Your PHP code is really a bad way of creating the JSON string you require:

There is a function called [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which will convert a Value into a JSON representation.

You can use `stdClass` to hold your information and simply turn the structure into a JSON String:

```
$personArray = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($sel)) {
    $person = new stdClasS();
    $person->name = $r[0];

    $personArray[] = $person;
}

$results = new stdClass();
$results->records = $personArray;

echo json_encode($results); // {"records":[{"name":"Stephen"},{"name":"Jane"},{"name":"Sam"}]}
```

Comment: If you navigated to http://localhost/demo/angular/getdata.php what do you see?  Also, if you just used {{list}} do you see your json results?  It's difficult to pin down just exactly what is the problem

Comment: I just spotted a typo in your code. I've updated my answer

Comment: output array : ["Reena","Diya","New","New1","Diya","Sonali","Sonali","Sonali"]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. Created a demo here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo for select box, AngularJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

       <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl" class="centered">
        <label>Select User</label>
      <!-- use item.Name instead of item.name as per JSON structure -->
        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.Name for item in list">
            <option value="">-- choose --</option>
        </select>
        <h2>Selected:</h2>
        {{selectedItem.Name}}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
        app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {

           // Assuming you're getting list from API in below format as per your sample JSON provided in a comment
            $scope.list = {"records":[{Name : "Reena"},{Name : "Diya"},{Name : "New"},{Name : "New1"},{Name : "Diya"},{Name : "Sonali" },{Name : "Sonali"},{Name : "Sonali"},]};

            // update list variable as your sample JSON has records field but in html you're using without it
            $scope.list = $scope.list.records;

            /*
            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : "http://localhost/demo/angular/getdata.php"
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.list = response.data.records;
            });
            */
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Working Fiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/sanmax/36axutzu/)

Comment: i want load user name from database

Comment: @ReenaMori: Can you please clear what output (response.data.records) you're getting from database under AJAX callback (i.e under $http => then callback function)?

Comment: output array : ["Reena","Diya","New","New1","Diya","Sonali","Sonali","Sonal‌​‌​i"]

Comment: Didn't get time to update. Here is updated Fiddle as per your modified JSON output: https://jsfiddle.net/sanmax/36axutzu/2/

Comment: i want load  this ["Reena","Diya","New","New1","Diya","Sonali","Sonali","Sonal‌​‌​‌​i"]  from database not a static